# win32_process.create does not show window

Tags: c#, win32-process

I'm trying to create a process on a remote machine using C#. 
I get all the needed parameters, and I actually succeed in running the process, but I can't see the window. 
For example, here I'm trying to run a notepad process, but no window is showing up, only a notepad.exe process in the Task Manager.

```
    public void ExecuteOnRemote(string username, string password)
    {
        ConnectionOptions connOptions = new ConnectionOptions 
                                        { 
                                            Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate, 
                                            EnablePrivileges = true,
                                            Username = username,
                                            Password = password
                                        };

        ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\remoteMachineName\root\cimv2", connOptions);
        scope.Connect();

        ObjectGetOptions options = new ObjectGetOptions();

        // Getting the process class and the process startup class
        ManagementPath processClassPath = new ManagementPath("Win32_Process");
        ManagementPath processStartupClassPath = new ManagementPath("Wind32_ProcessStartup");

        ManagementClass processClass = new ManagementClass(scope, processClassPath, options);
        ManagementClass processStartupClass = new ManagementClass(scope, processStartupClassPath, options);

        // Settings the show window parameter in for a process startup class instance
        ManagementObject processStartupInstance = processStartupClass.CreateInstance();
        processStartupInstance["ShowWindow"] = 1; // A const value for showing the window normally

        // Settings the parameters for the Create method in the process class
        ManagementBaseObject inArgs = processClass.GetMethodParameters("Create");
        inArgs["CommandLine"] = "notepad.exe";
        inArgs["ProcessStartupInformation"] = processStartupInstance;

        // Invoking the method
        ManagementBaseObject returnValue = processClass.InvokeMethod("Create", inArgs, null);
    }
```

My guess is that I'm sending the ProcessStartupInformation parameter wrong, but I still can't figure out where is the problem. 
Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks a lot, Alex.

Comment: Hmya, never underestimate Microsoft's concern for malicious use of this feature.  Displaying a window that looks like a login dialog is of course a good way to harvest passwords.  Your notepad.exe is displaying its window in the desktop for the isolated session 0.  Look at SysInternals' PsExec utility, -i option.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Didn't know it was a security feature. PsExec did the job for me. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft prohibits this **explicitly**.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389388(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389388%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> For security reasons the Win32_Process.Create method cannot be used to
>   start an interactive process remotely.

Answer (score 1):

```cs
ManagementPath processStartupClassPath = new ManagementPath("Win32_ProcessStartup");
```

You made a typo there.

Comment: Thanks, haven't noticed, but in the real code segment I didn't do the typo. Thanks anyway! :-)